# problem while using database column value into Date() sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

i have small problem, i googled it many times but i couldn't get it...
i'm using a query (sqlite) to retrieve some data  ..
in this query their is Date() used to increase certain date dynamic number of days (coming from column in the same table) ..
if i put this days static (1,2,3,.....) it works fine but if i put column name it doesn't.
this query fails and i want it to work:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + DATE + " = date('" + targetDate + "',' " + REPETITIONS + " day') ";
```

this works fine :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + DATE + " = date('" + targetDate + "','2 day') ";
```

where

> targetDate: date entered by user to get events of that date
>
> DATE: date of every event in the table
>
> REPETETIONS: dynamic number (column in the same table)

the problem is using REPETITIONS in the date function...

create statement

```
String SQL_CREATE_EVENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            TITLE + " TEXT ," +
            DATE + " TEXT , " +
            IS_NOTIFY + " INTEGER , " +
            NOTIFICATION_TIME + " TEXT ," +
            REPEAT + " INTEGER ," +
            REPEAT_DURATION + " INTEGER ," +
            REPETITIONS + " INTEGER ," +
            CERTAIN_DATE + " TEXT ," +
            NOTE + " TEXT ," +
            IS_SPOKEN + " INTEGER " +
            " );";
```

and this is the selecting statement

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DATE + " = '" + targetDate
            + "' OR (( " + REPEAT + " = '1' AND " + REPEAT_DURATION + " = '0' ) AND " + DATE + " <= '" + targetDate + "')"
            + " OR( " + REPEAT + " = '1' AND " + REPEAT_DURATION + " = '3' ) AND " + DATE + " <= '" + targetDate + "' AND " + CERTAIN_DATE + " >= '" + targetDate + "'"
            + " OR (" + REPEAT + " = '1' AND " + REPEAT_DURATION + "= '2' ) AND " + targetDate + " >= '" + DATE + "' AND "+ targetDate+ " <= date('" + DATE + "','" + REPETITIONS + " days')";
```

Comment: Can you please show the SQL statements that work and the SQL statements that don't work?

Comment: this is working


`String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + DATE + " = date('" + targetDate + "',' 2 day') ";`



but this not .
`String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + DATE + " = date('" + targetDate + "',' " + REPETITIONS + " day') ";`
@Corion

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information. Also, is this a query that works or a query that fails? Please also show a query that fails.

Comment: Is `REPETITIONS` a varaible in your main program? Otherwise you need to put the concatenation into the SQL. Print out the SQL you get before sending it to SQLite. It should look like `SELECT ... WHERE date_column = date('2018-10-28', to_char(repetitions)+' day')" or something like that.

Comment: i'm showing both works and fails ...
repetitions is global String which is the name of the column @Corion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `REPETITIONS` in this statement:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + DATE + " = date('" + targetDate + "',' " + REPETITIONS + " day') ";
```

should be a number and not a column name.  
The `date` function in SQLite has various syntaxes but you use this one:

```
SELECT date('2014-10-23','+7 day');
```

you must supply a number before `day`.

**Edit** try this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + DATE + " = date('" + targetDate + "', " + REPETITIONS + " || ' day') ";
```

Comment: but the number must be dynamic indpending on (repetitions) column in db

Comment: So in its place you must use an integer variable. What exactly do you want to select from the db?

Comment: how to use integer variable ...it's the name of the column cant be integer

Comment: i'm making calendar app ...and this query is part of big query getting events ...
i want to use it to get events with repetitions (with some calculations) doesn't matter now ...
the important thing now is to get repetitions value in this method

Comment: You can't use a string like a column name inside the date function. Say the name of the column is "REPETITIONS" then your statement would be: `... date('2/1/2018',' REPETITIONS day')` which is not a valid sql statement

Comment: Your problem will not be solved if you don't explain what you want to select from the table and of course post the create statement of the table so I know the structure of the table.

Comment: Did you try the latest, because I made modifications.

Comment: i noticed it and yea i did

Comment: One more to try

Answer (score 1):

In sqlite [`date()` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), the `NNN days` is a string modifier and not an expression. Therefore you cannot use column names or even `||` string concatenation there.

You can format the modifier string in your code and place it in the SQL. This requires additional query to the database, which is likely not what you want.

If you can assume each day is 24 hours (which is not always true, consider e.g. DST events), you could try something like

```
... date(strftime('%s', '" + targetDate + "', " + REPETITIONS + "*24*60*60, 'unixepoch') ...
```

where `strftime('%s', ...)` converts to seconds and `date(..., 'unixepoch')` converts back to datestamp.

But seriously I'd consider redesigning the schema to better support your functional requirements.

Comment: i have to design my schema this way ...
because events have many types of repetition ..
event repeats daily ..
event repeats daily till certain date ..
event repeats daily for x times ..
...... etc 
if any idea for 3rd type ?
and thanks for ur comment